# I want to build a zip code handler program which will remove any non-digit character in the zip code and print the formatted zip

Tags: java, regex

To remove any non-digit character from the zip code entered I have used regular expression for non-digits="\D". But the program is not able to handle white spaces within zipcode. e.g. Whenever "12 4-67_9" is entered it is printing the formatted zipcode as "12" instead of the intended "124679".

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class ZipCodeHandler {
    static String zip,zip5,zip4;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the zip code: ");
        zip=s.next();
        //Regular expression for Non-digits
        String regex="\\D";             
        String[] zip1=zip.split(regex);     
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<zip1.length;i++) {
            builder.append(zip1[i]);
        }
        zip=builder.toString();
        System.out.println("The formated zip code is: "+zip);       
    }
}
```

output:
Please enter the zip code: 
12 4-67_9
The formated zip code is: 12

Comment: Scanner.next() will stop at the space

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` objects have a delimiter. From the [Javadoc for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

When you call `Scanner.next()`, the Scanner reads until it hits this delimiter and then stops reading. If you want the entire line, use `Scanner.nextLine()` instead.

There is a much easier way to remove everything matching a particular pattern from a string. [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) takes a regex as one of its arguments. You can replace all non-digits in a single, fairly readable line of code:

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

Your program then becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the zip code: ");  
    String line = s.nextLine();
    line = line.replaceAll("\\D","");
    System.out.println("The formatted zip code is: " + line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using s.next(), try s.nextLine(). Check out the differences of [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) and [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class ZipCodeHandler {
    static String zip,zip5,zip4;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the zip code: ");
        zip=s.nextLine();
        //Regular expression for Non-digits
        String regex="\\D";             
        String[] zip1=zip.split(regex);     
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<zip1.length;i++) {
            builder.append(zip1[i]);
        }
        zip=builder.toString();
        System.out.println("The formated zip code is: "+zip);       
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to say "If this helped you understand the problem and how to solve it, please mark as answer."